# Checking that the bundle is autoloaded: FAILED

Tags: symfony

I cannot create a bundle. I'm getting "Checking that the bundle is autoloaded: FAILED" which never used to happen before until now. Steps below always worked until today.

Any solutions?

**To setup Symfony2:**

I downloaded: `Symfony_Standard_Vendors_2.4.5.zip`

I unzipped under: `/var/www/html/local/three`. **three** is the main folder.

I set the permissions:

```
desktop@ubuntu:/var/www/html/local/three$ sudo chown desktop -R app/logs
desktop@ubuntu:/var/www/html/local/three$ sudo chown desktop -R app/cache
desktop@ubuntu:/var/www/html/local/three$ sudo chmod 777 -R app/cache
desktop@ubuntu:/var/www/html/local/three$ sudo chmod 777 -R app/logs
```

This URL works fine: `http://localhost/local/three/web/app_dev.php`

**To create my bundle:**

```
desktop@ubuntu:/var/www/html/local/three$ php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Myblog/PublicBundle


      Welcome to the Symfony2 bundle generator  



    In your code, a bundle is often referenced by its name. It can be the
    concatenation of all namespace parts but it's really up to you to come
    up with a unique name (a good practice is to start with the vendor name).
    Based on the namespace, we suggest MyblogPublicBundle.

    Bundle name [MyblogPublicBundle]: 

    The bundle can be generated anywhere. The suggested default directory uses
    the standard conventions.

    Target directory [/var/www/html/local/three/app/cache/dev/../src]: 

    Determine the format to use for the generated configuration.

    Configuration format (yml, xml, php, or annotation): yml

    To help you get started faster, the command can generate some
    code snippets for you.

    Do you want to generate the whole directory structure [no]? yes


      Summary before generation  


    You are going to generate a "Myblog\PublicBundle\MyblogPublicBundle" bundle
    in "/var/www/html/local/three/app/cache/dev/../src/" using the "yml" format.

    Do you confirm generation [yes]? yes


      Bundle generation  


    Generating the bundle code: OK
    Checking that the bundle is autoloaded: FAILED
    Confirm automatic update of your Kernel [yes]? yes
    Enabling the bundle inside the Kernel: OK
    Confirm automatic update of the Routing [yes]? yes
    Importing the bundle routing resource: OK


      The command was not able to configure everything automatically.  
      You must do the following changes manually.                      


    - Edit the composer.json file and register the bundle
      namespace in the "autoload" section:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:

Problem is to do with line:

```
Target directory [/var/www/html/local/three/app/cache/dev/../src]:
```

I don't understand why it is suggesting `cache` path. Old days it was always automatically suggesting **src** directory instead. I've checked my logs that's why I know. Anyway change it to:

```
/var/www/html/local/three/src
```

Done!

Comment: I just came this very same issue, any idea what caused the change in the Target directory?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue now, I guess it will be fixed on the next version

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/10972

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/10999

https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/issues/659

for now when the generate:bundle displays this:

> The bundle can be generated anywhere. The suggested default directory
> uses the standard conventions.
>
> Target directory:
> -- /type/your/directory/src here